# Connecting multiple devices on static IP Internet connection

Tags: ip, dhcp

I have to set up remote back infrastructure for my company. The software I am using requires FTP server for remote backup. I am using QNAP NAS box the same which provides a built in FTP server.
I have an Internet connection and planning to get static IP for this connection via my ISP. I am planning to connect my QNAP NAS Box on this Internet connection (with static IP provided by my ISP) as FTP based remote backup server.
I wish to conform if I connect my NAS Box on this connection, can I also connect other devices like mobile phones, laptops, etc. with DHCP on the same Internet connection. Will this cause conflict with my remote backup solution.

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to use a single (dynamic or static) IP address for more than one device you need to set up a NAT router. Any access router should be able to do it. Local devices can get dynamic, private addresses from a DHCP server and the NAT router provides private/public address translation (source NAT).

Any device you need to be accessed from the Internet needs to be port-mapped on the router (also called destination NAT/DNAT or reverse NAT).

*However,* any device visible to the Internet will be *exposed to hackers* as well. You'll need a tight, secure setup and encryption on the connection. If the mapped device can't reliably provide that you'll need to use VPN.

Comment: I thought this was off topic..

Answer (score 0):

Port forwarding/NAT would be a best option.

Your only need is a router which supports port forwarding/NAT and as far i know now a days all routers are supporting this feature.

You also need to make sure that same service from multiple device will not work unless you change the port to access & you are highly check that services not keep open directly which may result in hacking purpose.